# How to move a div element with React statement property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am starting a music track app and i created 2 tracklist in React. I do also have created a Track element where there is a button that suppose to move onClick to a tracklist to an other.

Unfortunatly for me, after several try, i couldn't figure how make update the statement in order to move this Track element to an other list.

Here is my code in Github

https://github.com/erwanriou/jamming/tree/master/src/components

and an extract of what the 2 elements that are probably with the bug :

TRACKLIST

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../track/Track.js';


class TrackList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { position: 0 }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ position: (this.state.position + 1) % 2 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackLists">
        <div className="TrackList1">
          <div className="TrackListTitle">
            <h2>Results</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="TrackListcontent">
            { this.state.position === 0 ? <Track onClick={this.onClick}/> : ''}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="TrackList2">
          <div className="TrackListTitle">
            <h2>NewPlaylist</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="TrackListcontent">
            { this.state.position === 1 ? <Track onClick={this.onClick}/> : ''}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

TRACK

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css'

class Track extends React.Component {

 render() {

    let trackName = "Sweet Disposition";
    let trackAlbum = "The Temper Trap";
    let trackArtist = "Bootleg";

    return (
      <div className="track">
        <div className="trackText">
          <h2>{trackName}</h2>
          <p>{trackAlbum} - {trackArtist}</p>
        </div>
        <i onClick={this.props.onClick} className="fas fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Track;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a moment and reconsider your approach. A more object oriented approach to the problem would mean that you have two trackList components, and a button that would move a track from one trackList component to the other. Under the hood, you will perhaps move a track component from one array in one TrackListComponent, into the corresponding array of the other trackListComponent...

Comment: Thanks for the information, i did started with 2 different array trackList at the start but as i am quite inexperimented with React, i couldn't figure how to connect the "button" element to make pass one to an other.

Also this button have to be inside the track himself if possible. Have you any référence of a similar code where i could learn this logic. I do understund a bit how work the props/state functionnality but didn't figure out how i could use it in this case.... Lack of imagination i imagine.